# Please solve this error as soon as possible

Tags: android, flutter, dart, get

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 37, column 3: Expected ':'.
╷
37 │   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2:
│   ^
╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Androidstudio\Projects_8.whatsappclone\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

Remove the colon after dependency's version code

From this:

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2:

To this:

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

Comment: Ahh, thank you but this one is solved by correct indention.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the colon near the cupertino_icons version.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2: -> cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

then run `flutter pub get` again